# Add spans to characters in a string (in an HTML element)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop through the characters of a text in an element and add `span`s to the characters. This is pretty easy using [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
$elem = $('h1');
var chars = jQuery.map($elem.text().split(''), function(c) {
  return '<span>' + c + '</span>';
});
$elem.html(chars.join(''));
```

The above [works great with a simple string](http://jsfiddle.net/F7KqP/), but now I want to change the function so that it also will handle more 'complex' contents like: `<h1>T<em>e</em><b>st</b></h1>`. Which should be translated to: `<h1><span>T</span><em><span>e</span></em><b><span>s</span><span>t</span></b></h1>`.

This means I cannot simply loop through all the characters in the element anymore. Is there something I can use to loop through the contents (characters) of an element as well as all children? Or is there another way of achieveing what I want?

Comment: Use jQuery's filter to filter out just the textnodes and run those in your map.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Overall idea:**

You can recursively iterate over the child nodes. If you encounter an element node, you iterate over its children etc. If you encounter a text node, you are replacing it with a series of `span` elements.

---

**jQuery**

```
function wrapCharacters(element) {
    $(element).contents().each(function() {
        if(this.nodeType === 1) {
            wrapCharacters(this);
        }
        else if(this.nodeType === 3) {
            $(this).replaceWith($.map(this.nodeValue.split(''), function(c) {
               return '<span>' + c + '</span>';
            }).join(''));
        }
    });
}    

wrapCharacters($('h1')[0]);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a7N3F/)

---

**JavaScript (without jQuery)**

The idea stays the same, and even without jQuery, wrapping each character is not very difficult:

```
var d_ = document.createDocumentFragment();

for(var i = 0, len = this.nodeValue.length; i < len; i++) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = this.nodeValue.charAt(i);
    d_.appendChild(span);
}
// document fragments are awesome :)
this.parentNode.replaceChild(d_, this);
```

Only iterating over the child nodes has to be done carefully because text nodes are getting removed during iteration.

[**Plain JavaScript example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6bEuW/)

Comment: Usually a lot quicker to make one span and clone it rather than using createElement. Might also be much faster to replace an entire text node in one go using something like `element.innerHTML = '<span>' + textNode.data.split('').join('<\/span><span>') + '<\/span>';` or similar. That wraps whitespace too, maybe not what the OP wanted?

Comment: Yeah, cloning is probably faster. But `replaceChild` will replace the whole text node at once as well. Setting the content of a text node to an HTML string has worked for me so far (the text node was then replaced by the element nodes) but I don't know if this behaviour is consistent between browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like (untested):

```
function recursivelyWrapTextNodes($node) {
  $node.contents().each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (this.nodeType === 3) { //Node.TEXT_NODE (IE...)
        var spans = $.each($this.text().split(""), function(index, element) {
            var $span = $("<span></span>");
            $span.text(element);
            $span.insertBefore($this);
        });
        $this.remove();
    }
    else if (this.nodeType === 1) //Node.ELEMENT_NODE
    recursivelyWrapTextNodes($this);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ymcha/

Comment: You forgot to wrap each character.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks - just corrected this and added an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure javascript solution

```js
/**
 * Enclose every character of a string into a span
 * @param text Text whose characters will be spanned
 * @returns {string} The "spanned" string
 */
function spanText(text) {
    return "<span class='char'>" +
        text.split("").join("<\/span><span class='char'>") + "<\/span>";
}

var text = "Every character will be in a span";
document.getElementById("testContent").innerHTML = spanText(text);

document.getElementById("showSpans").textContent = spanText(text);
```

```css
.char{background-color: grey;}
```

```html
<! --- Demo for spanning all characters -->
<h3> Spanned text is highlighted grey </h3>
<p id="testContent"> Spanned material here</p>

<h3> This is how the above Highlighted text looks </h3>
<p id="showSpans"></p>
```