# What is a wrap method to wrap only a part of a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, highlight

I have an HTML like this:

```
<div>
     <h3>How are you? Fine?</h3>
</div>
```

I would like to turn that in something different, using two numbers n and m, something like:
if n=5 and m=12

```
<div>
     <h3>How 
            <span class="yellow">are you?</span>
      Fine?</h3>
</div>
```

In other words I would like to "highlight" only a part of a string using two numbers that specifies the start and the end of the "highlight" (in characters).

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
//in the previous example it will be a xpath selector for div/h3
var selection=$(document.body).xpath(selector).text();

//it will be "are you?"
var substring=selection.substring(n,m);

//it would make that i want, but it doesn't
                                $(document.body).xpath(selector).contents().filter(function() {
                        return substring;
                    }).wrap("<span class=\"yellow\"></span>");
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452340/iterating-through-each-text-element-in-a-page) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666277/add-spans-to-characters-in-a-string-in-an-html-element) answer could help you

Comment: What xpath plugin are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be - instead of wrap, replace the content of the h3 with the slice up manipulated version.

See this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9LeL3f3n/21/

```
<div>
    <h3>How are you? Fine?</h3>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {

    var highlight = function(str, start, end) {
      return str.slice(0,start-1) + 
        '<span style="color:#ffff00">' + 
        str.substring(start-1, end) + 
        '</span>' +  
        str.slice(-1 * (str.length - end));
    };

    var n = 5;
    var m = 12;

    $('h3').html(highlight($('h3').html(),n,m)); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest writing your own plugin to achieve this, if only because it would appear to be something useful for repeated use. That said, I'd offer the following approach, which effectively splits the textNode nodes, using `textNode.splitText()` and appending the relevant portion to a created element before re-inserting that node, and surrounding textNodes back into the parent element:

```
// a simple plugin approach, taken from:
// https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/
(function ($) {

    // defining the name of the plugin ('highlight'):
    $.fn.highlight = function (opts) {

        // the default settings, used if no arguments are
        // passed into the plugin via the 'opts' Object:
        var settings = {
            'start' : 0,
            'end' : 1,
            'wrapper' : 'span',
            'class' : 'highlight',
            'css' : {
                'color' : 'yellow'
            }
        },
            // 'empty' declared variables for later use:
            node, textMiddle, textEnd;

        // iterating over the 'opts' Object using
        // a for...in loop:
        for (var prop in opts) {

            // if the 'opts' Object has an own property 'prop'
            // (not one inherited from its prototype chain):
            if (opts.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

                // we update the 'settings' Object to
                // be equal to the 'opts' Object property-value:
                settings[prop] = opts[prop];
            }
        }

        // using parseInt() to ensure that we're working
        // with numbers, rather than strings, and that those
        // numbers are in base-10:
        settings.start = parseInt(settings.start, 10);
        settings.end = parseInt(settings.end, 10);

        // normalising the settings.wrapper string, ensuring that
        // if the user passes in '<span>' (or '<<<<<span>', etc)
        // we remove those (this could be made even safer by only
        // allowing the first consecutive string of alphabetical
        // characters):
        settings.wrapper = settings.wrapper.replace(/<|>/g,'');

        // here we iterate over, and return, the jQuery collection
        // to allow for chaining to continue (here 'this' is the
        // jQuery collection of nodes/elements):
        return this.each(function () {

            // here this is the DOM node from the collection.

            // and here we iterate over the childNodes of each
            // DOM node from that collection:
            $(this).contents().each(function () {

                // if the current childNode is nodeType 3 (a textNode)
                // AND the length of the nodeValue (the text itself)
                // is greater than, or equal to, the settings.end:
                if (this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.length >= settings.end) {

                    // we create a new element equal to the
                    // settings.wrapper argument passed in by
                    // the user (or the default):
                    node = document.createElement(settings.wrapper);

                    // if we have a settings.css Object:
                    if (settings.css) {

                        // we iterate over that Object with a
                        // for...in loop (as above):
                        for (var prop in settings.css){
                            if (settings.css.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

                                // setting the node's style property
                                // to be equal to the property-value
                                // of the settings.css Object:
                                node.style[prop] = settings.css[prop];
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // if we have a settings.class:
                    if (settings.class) {

                        // we use Array.prototype.forEach
                        Array.prototype.forEach
                          // with Function.prototype.call()
                          // to iterate over the resulting array
                          // of splitting the settings.class
                          // String on white-space characters:
                          .call(settings.class.split(/\s+/),
                              // the 'classname' argument is the
                              // class-name from the string, now
                              // in the Array over which we're iterating:
                              function (classname) {

                                  // here we add the trimmed classname
                                  // string (removing the leading and
                                  // trailing white=space) to the
                                  // list of classes of the node:
                                  node.classList.add(classname.trim());
                              });
                    }

                    // here we split the textNode (this) using
                    // Text.splitText(offset); which converts
                    // one textNode into two separate textNodes
                    // and returns the second (newly-created) 
                    // textNode ('this' remains 'this' but with
                    // shortened text):
                    textMiddle = this.splitText(settings.start);

                    // and again, but this time we have to compensate
                    // for already shortening the textNode, and
                    // and so subtract the offset from the settings.end:
                    textEnd = textMiddle.splitText(settings.end - settings.start);

                    // appending the textNode to the created
                    // element:
                    node.appendChild(textMiddle);

                    // inserting the created node after the original
                    // textNode:                        
                    this.parentNode.insertBefore(node, this.nextSibling);


                }
            });

        });
    };

// passing jQuery into the plugin in order to allow us to use
// the $ alias within the plugin:
})(jQuery);

// using the plugin:
$('div h3').highlight({
    // setting the 'start' offset:
    'start' : 4,
    // the end index/offset:
    'end' : 12,
    // specifying classes to add to the created element(s):
    'class' : 'highlight classes',
    // setting the CSS properties of the created element(s):
    'css' : {
        'color' : '#f89',
        'text-decoration' : 'underline'
    }
});
```

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.highlight = function(opts) {
    var settings = {
        'start': 0,
        'end': 1,
        'wrapper': 'span',
        'class': 'highlight',
        'css': {
          'color': 'yellow'
        }
      },
      node, textMiddle, textEnd;

    for (var prop in opts) {
      if (opts.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        settings[prop] = opts[prop];
      }
    }

    settings.wrapper = settings.wrapper.replace(/<|>/g, '');

    return this.each(function() {

      $(this).contents().each(function() {
        if (this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.length >= settings.end) {
          node = document.createElement(settings.wrapper);

          if (settings.css) {
            for (var prop in settings.css) {
              if (settings.css.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                node.style[prop] = settings.css[prop];
              }
            }
          }

          if (settings.class) {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(settings.class.split(/\s+/), function(classname) {
              node.classList.add(classname.trim());
            });
          }

          textMiddle = this.splitText(settings.start);
          textEnd = textMiddle.splitText(settings.end - settings.start);
          node.appendChild(textMiddle);

          this.parentNode.insertBefore(node, this.nextSibling);


        }
      });

    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('div h3').highlight({
  'start': 4,
  'end': 12,
  'class': 'highlight classes',
  'css': {
    'color': '#f89',
    'text-decoration': 'underline'
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  font-style: italic;
}
.classes {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>How are you? Fine?</h3>
</div>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/krra8o56/1/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`For...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
  - [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).
  - [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).
  - [`Node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue).
  - [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
  - [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).
  - [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
  - [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
  - [`Text.splitText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/splitText).
- jQuery:

  - [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - "[How to Create a Basic Plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)."